# Swift Xcode 11.4. add back button to the TableView navigation item

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to add "Close" or "Back" button onto TableViewController visited by segue. I am using Storyboard. I am unable to move the elements I want to. And this is not working.

[image: xcode]

What am I doing wrong please? How can I add back or close button into header (or navbar) of this controller.

Result is

[image: screen]

that I don't have title or Back. If I embed it in Navigation controller, I have just title, but without any buttons or navs.

If I embed TableView controller into Navigation Controller, I got this

[image]

I can see it right there, but not working.

[image]

and here

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Kind option in Storyboard segue settings to `Show`. You will have back button created automatically.

[image]

Comment: I tried, with no change :(. TableView is called from another table view, when I don't use Nav.controller, even title disappears. Running out of options.

Comment: Just add another Nav.controller embedded in final table view